# How do I use Zen HTML in PHP files in PhpStorm 8?

Tags: php, phpstorm, workflow, emmet, code-templates

How do I use Zen HTML Live Templates in PHP files in PhpStorm 8 without having to edit every live 'Zen HTML' Template individually to be applicable in HTML and in PHP. As it stands they only work in HTML files.

Comment: Heh? Care to explain what you mean by "having to edit every entry manually"?

Comment: I improved the question. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Better .. but not yet. Please show a screenshot with the place where you having problems with such live template. It works fine for me in `.php` files -- not inside `<?php ?>` tags .. but where HTML context is applicable, of course.

Comment: You are right, I realised that it was because I was using a new `.php` file and PhpStorm creates each `.php` file with opening `<?php ` tags and I was trying inside them. I had been at the computer for way too long. I'm quite new at all of this, thank you for answering, apologies if I wasted your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It works fine for me in `.php` files -- not inside `<?php ?>` tags"
As it turns out, I was trying this within `<?php ?>`!